# gulp-csslint error on running gulp with MeanJS wrapper

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, gulp, meanjs

I installed meanJS. I run into this error on running gulp/ grunt. 

Node v6.2.2

npm v3.9.5

MeanJS v0.4.2

> ../node_modules/gulp-csslint/node_modules/rcloader/index.js:36
>   
>   if (err) throw err;
>   
>             ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.csslintrc'
>     at Error (native)

I have tried reinstalling from scratch and nvm as well. Even yo seems to not work. No idea what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 files:

.csslintrc:

```
{
  "adjoining-classes": false,
  "box-model": false,
  "box-sizing": false,
  "floats": false,
  "font-sizes": false,
  "important": false,
  "known-properties": false,
  "overqualified-elements": false,
  "qualified-headings": false,
  "regex-selectors": false,
  "unique-headings": false,
  "universal-selector": false,
  "unqualified-attributes": false
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb/legacy'
  ],
  rules: {
    camelcase: 0,
    'comma-dangle': [2, 'never'],
    'comma-spacing': [2, { before: false, after: true }],
    'consistent-return': 0,
    curly: 0,
    'default-case': 0,
    eqeqeq: [2, 'smart'],
    'func-names': 0,
    'guard-for-in': 2,
    indent: [2, 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
    'key-spacing': [2, { beforeColon: false, afterColon: true }],
    'keyword-spacing': [2, { before: true, after: true }],
    'max-len': 0,
    'new-cap': [2, { newIsCapExceptions: ['acl.memoryBackend', 'acl'] }],
    'no-bitwise': 0,
    'no-caller': 2,
    'no-console': 0,
    'no-else-return': 0,
    'no-empty-class': 0,
    'no-multi-spaces': 2,
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'no-spaced-func': 2,
    'no-throw-literal': 2,
    'no-trailing-spaces': 2,
    'no-undef': 2,
    'no-unneeded-ternary': 2,
    'no-unreachable': 2,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'no-unused-expressions': 0,
    'no-unused-vars': 0,
    'no-use-before-define': [1, 'nofunc'],
    'no-var': 0,
    'object-curly-spacing': [2, 'always'],
    'one-var': [0, 'never'],
    'one-var-declaration-per-line': [2, 'always'],
    'padded-blocks': 0,
    'space-before-function-paren': 0,
    'space-in-parens': [2, 'never'],
    'spaced-comment': [2, 'always'],
    strict: 0,
    'quote-props': 0,
    quotes: [1, 'single'],
    'wrap-iife': [2, 'outside'],
    'vars-on-top': 0
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    browser: true,
    jasmine: true,
    mocha: true,
    jquery: true
  },
  globals: {
    angular: true,
    by: true,
    browser: true,
    element: true,
    inject: true,
    io: true,
    moment: true,
    Modernizr: true,
    Promise: true,
    __TESTING__: true,
    _: false,
    ApplicationConfiguration: true
  }
};
```